# Search for numbers in a string

Tags: teradata

I am using teradata 15, and want to search those rows which contains 4 digit number in a varchar column.I tried to use below:

column1 like  '[^0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][^0-9]'

but it didn't help. Any help will be helpful.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you provide examples of what you want to match and what you want to exclude?

Comment: @trey .. Should Match: ' i have a product whose upc code is 034727432754 and need to replace' ; Shouldn'tMatch: ' I have a product which is not good and should be replaced'

Answer (score 4):

Teradata only supports Standard SQL `LIKE`, but there's `REGEXP_SIMILAR`, too. This is your LIKE as regex:

```
where regexp_similar(column1, '[^0-9][0-9]{4}[^0-9]') = 1
```

Edit:

Based on your added example you want to find at least for consecutive digits within an arbitrary string:

```
regexp_similar(column1, '.*[0-9]{4,}.*')
```